# Geometry-Triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle with $DAE$, a straight line parallel to BC such that $DA=AE$. If $CD$ meets $AB$ at X and $BE$ meets $AC$ at $Y$, prove that $XY$ is parallel to $BC$

I tried to use the angle approach by couldn't work out the problem as I couldn't effectively prove the thing using alternate angles approach.

Comment: It would really help if you could post an image!

Comment: I don't think this is true- maybe "prove that $XY$ is parallel to $AB$" has a typo ? When I draw it with an equilateral triangle, it looks nowhere near to true

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Sorry for the mistake. Now i have rectified it.

Comment: A picture is worth $10^3$ words.

Comment: Use geoGebra, https://www.geogebra.org/geometry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

We have that $\triangle{AXD}$ and $\triangle{BXC}$ are similar and that $\triangle{EYA}$ and $\triangle{BYC}$ are similar, and so
$$AX:BX=AD:BC=AE:BC=AY:CY$$
from which the claim follows.